# "cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null" error

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting the error "cannot read property'innerHTML' of null" at line 11 in the file letterbyletter.js. Its code is this:

```js
function printLetterByLetter(destination, message, speed){
    let h = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        if (h===0) {
            stop=false
        }
        if (h > message.length||(stop===true&&h!==0)){
            clearInterval(interval);
            stop=false
        }else if (message.charAt(h)!=="<") {
            document.getElementById(destination).innerHTML += message.charAt(h);
            h++;
        }else {
            document.getElementById(destination).innerHTML += "<br>"
            h+=4
        }
    }, speed);
}
```

It is being called here:

```js
function run(num9) {
    if (stats[3][1]>enemies[num9].speed) {
        let r=Math.ceil(Math.random()*100)
        if (r>=50) {
            battlechk=false
            document.getElementById("body").innerHTML="<div class=\"textbox\" id=\"textbox\"></div>"
            printLetterByLetter("textbox","You escaped from "+enemies[num9].name+"!",50)
            document.getElementById("body").innerHTML+="<button class=\"option\" onclick=\"supdateGUI3()\">Confirm</button>"
        }else {
            document.getElementById("body").innerHTML="<div class=\"textbox\" id=\"textbox\"></div>"
            printLetterByLetter("textbox",enemies[num9].name+" blocks your path! "+enemies[num9].name+" attacks you!",50)
            document.getElementById("body").innerHTML+="<button class=\"option\" onclick=\"battle("+num9+")\">Confirm</button>"
        }
    }else {
        let r=Math.ceil(Math.random()*100)
        if (r>=90) {
            battlechk=false
            document.getElementById("body").innerHTML="<div class=\"textbox\" id=\"textbox\"></div>"
            printLetterByLetter("textbox","You escaped from "+enemies[num9].name+"!",50)
            document.getElementById("body").innerHTML+="<button class=\"option\" onclick=\"supdateGUI3()\">Confirm</button>"
        }else {
            document.getElementById("body").innerHTML="<div class=\"textbox\" id=\"textbox\"></div>"
            printLetterByLetter("textbox",enemies[num9].name+" blocks your path! "+enemies[num9].name+" attacks you!",50)
            document.getElementById("body").innerHTML+="<button class=\"option\" onclick=\"battle("+num9+")\">Confirm</button>"
        }
    }
    battle(num9)
}
```

Every one of the calls in the above code cause the same error. A deeper look reveals that the textbox is there when printLetterByLetter is called and that the destination is textbox. When I console logged document.getElementById(destination) I got null. printLetterByLetter has worked every other time I have used it and I haven't gotten an error when I have used other commands that are similar. My entire code can be found here: https://github.com/Fish767/Space-Clones. The files in question are run.js and letterbyletter.js. Destination is a string and the line before I called printLetterByletter I added the element with an id of textbox.

Steps to reproduce: press move and left twice and then move and explore until you get into a battle. Then press run.

The html doc is this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/first.css">
    <title id="title">Lives in Space</title>
</head>
<body id="body">
    <script src="js/globalvars.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sleep.js"></script>
    <script src="js/letterbyletter.js"></script>
    <script src="js/format.js"></script>
    <script src="js/cleardoc.js"></script>
    <script src="js/doEffects.js"></script>
    <script src="js/use.js"></script>
    <script src="js/toss.js"></script>
    <script src="js/battleresults.js"></script>
    <script src="js/friend.js"></script>
    <script src="js/run.js"></script>
    <script src="js/attack.js"></script>
    <script src="js/battle.js"></script>
    <script src="js/event.js"></script>
    <script src="js/explore.js"></script>
    <script src="js/moveto.js"></script>
    <script src="js/second.js"></script>
    <script src="js/rpgland.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loop.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can easily do what I want in another way. What I am asking is why doesn't this way work.

Comment: is `destination` a string? Does an element have the `id="textbox"` ?

Comment: Where is the html element with id `textbox`

Comment: Yes, destination is a string and I added the element the line before I called printLetterByLetter.

Comment: Ececute the code on load event

Comment: I cloned your repo, dropped index.html in Chrome, played around, and I got no error.

Comment: What does "on load event" mean?

Comment: Did you press the run button after getting into a battle?

Comment: @Fish767 `destionation` cannot be a string, it must be an html object, else you cannot use `.getlElementById()`. Would you mind to add an html snippet to your question?

Comment: What battle? I didn't go that far. Please explain exactly what the problem is and the steps to reproduce. About the load event, it means waiting for all the HTML code to load before executing the JS, but in your case it's irrelevant, because all the JS code is loaded after the HTML anyway.

Comment: Steps to reproduce have been added

Comment: Destination must be a string because it is used in getElementById which takes a string. It is the id that is being called and not the object itself.

Comment: I got the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null`, which means that there is no element with id="textbox" in the document. Indeed, if you inspect the DOM, there is no element "#textbox" to be found. There is a `div id="statsbox"`, a `div id="options-container"`, a `div id="x"` and that's about it.

Comment: @JeremyThille when I console logged document.getElementById.(destination) at the begining of printLetterByletter it returned the object. In the middle of printLetterByLetter it returned null. I am trying to figure out how it disappeared within 10 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cloned the repo.

There is no "#textbox" in DOM when the error happen, it was replaced with "#statsbox" on `battle` function. You'll want to use chrome dev tool to debug step by step and it'll help you develop this game more easier also.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes I can be a real bonehead

Comment: Really admire at your game, you're a good developer, hard-working and passionate.

Comment: Thanks! This is my first big project and I want to make it a good one. I have been working on it for a couple of days now. As I progress in developing it I am going to upload it to GitHub. If you want to make suggestions as the game keeps going you can join my discord channel. https://discord.gg/bNe92FY

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you click the "confirm" button, you execute `battle(0)`, and the first instruction in this function is to overwrite the entire DOM : `document.getElementById("body").innerHTML="<div id=\"statsbox\"></div><div id=\"option-container\"></div>"`. So everything else disappears.

The reason why you can `console.log` the element at the beginning of `printLetterByLetter()` and then 10 lines later it logs `null` is because those 10 lines are within a `setInterval` which gets executed later, at the end of the lifecycle. The DOM has been overwritten in-between.

Comment: What happened is that I left a battle(num9) at the bottom of run.js. I didn't want that there. The buttons are supposed to do that and I have added safety measures in my code to make sure an error like that doesn't happen when the buttons are used.